# gazebo crashes when calling delete_model service call

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I use ros-cturtle-pr2all,
I found when I add an object and select it and delete that model and select gazebo again,
the gazebo will disappeared.
I can repeat this situation.

step:
1.open gazebo:
roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch

2.add an object:
sam@sam-laptop:~/code/ros/cad/stl$ rosrun gazebo spawn_model -file top.urdf -urdf -model top -z 0.5
loading model xml from file
attempting to spawn robot in simulation
waiting for service spawn_urdf_model
spawn status:  SpawnModel: successfully spawned model
spawning success True
sam@sam-laptop:~/code/ros/cad/stl$

3.select that object (ctrl+left mouse click)
It will show circles around that object

4.delete that model
sam@sam-laptop:~/code/ros/cad/stl$ rosservice call gazebo/delete_model '{model_name: top}'
success: True
status_message: DeleteModel: successfully deleted model
sam@sam-laptop:~/code/ros/cad/stl$

5.select gazebo flat world again(ctrl+left mouse click)
Gazebo will disappeared.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9211/gazebo-crashes-when-calling-delete_model-service-call/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2011-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-02-26**:
Yes,I have to restart gazebo to continue my work. Sorry for using misunderstanding word.

**Comment by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) on 2011-02-26**:
by  "disappearing" do you mean gazebo crashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yep, you've found a bug.  I needed to do

> gazebo::World::Instance()->SetSelectedEntity(NULL);

before calling `DeleteEntity(...)`.

[Ticketed with patch for unstable](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4831).

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2